Can porous metal electrodes with oxide layers work better than activated carbon in capacitors?
I’ve been reading about activated carbon capacitors (like supercapacitors). They use the huge surface area of porous carbon and ions movement in electrolyte to store energy. But they seem to have some limits, like:

Low voltage ratings (around 2.7–3V per cell).
Moderate current handling because carbon isn’t a great conductor.

This got me thinking: what if instead of activated carbon, we used metal plates (like aluminum or titanium) and made them porous by leaching (e.g., dissolving out parts of an alloy to leave holes)? After that, we could coat the porous metal with an oxide layer: Aluminum oxide for aluminum or Titanium dioxide for titanium. Then, the idea is to use these metal electrodes in an electrolyte that doesn’t corrode the oxide layer.
Why This Might Work

Higher Voltage: Metal oxide layers can handle much higher voltages than the electric double layer in activated carbon.
Dielectric Constant: The oxide layers have a much higher dielectric constant than the electric double layer in activated carbon, which could significantly increase the capacitance for the same surface area.
Better Conductivity: Aluminum and titanium conduct electricity way better than carbon, so current handling and energy loss might improve.
Durability: Metals are more durable than activated carbon

Questions

Would this work for making a capacitor with high capacitance, voltage ratings and energy density?
Is it realistic to get enough surface area from the porous metal compared to activated carbon?
Could there be issues with forming a good oxide layer on a porous structure?
What kind of electrolyte would be needed to make this stable and efficient?
Any other issues?

I’d love to hear your thoughts or if you’ve seen anything similar. Thanks!

This is indeed how tantalum capacitors work. You make a porous tantalum pill and chemically grow a thin oxide on the surface of it, then pack the pores with something conductive. The unoxidized Ta forms one plate of the capacitor and the conductive substance stuffed into the pores is the other. the thinness of the oxide combined with the huge surface area yields a lot of microfarads in a very small package.
It is also how electrolytic capacitors work: here you start with a thin foil of aluminum in contact with a chemical that oxidizes the aluminum when you apply a voltage to the aluminum. this thin oxide acts as the dielectric between the aluminum and a counter-electrode nearby and because it is very thin, the resulting capacitor represents lots of microfarads.
But if you hook up the capacitor with the wrong polarity, the applied voltage dissolves the dielectric and lets the two plates short-circuit one another, causing the capacitor to violently explode.
We therefore model a reversed-polarity electrolytic cap as a one-shot noise emitter.
